# Javascript nextSibling vs nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript, html, nextsibling

Greetings fellow coder,

I'm reading a book about JS ( beginners edition ) . I am on previous and next sibling properties.

I'm a little confused. I'm trying to run this demo code:

```
var el = document.getElementById('two');
```

When I `console.log(el.nextSibling);` it shows `#text`.

When I use `console.log(el.nextElementSibling);` it shows the correct results which is the next `li` element: `<li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>`

In the book it's saying that using `.nextSibling` will jump to the next Sibling element which it doesn't. Can someone explain me the difference?

Thank you!

Comment: yea maybe, so i guess the book is wrong on that subject and its confusing the reader because its explaining that it should jump to the next element . But the nextSibling it jump to the next node